# Can I select multiple objects in a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, list

Can I return more than one item in a select?  For instance I have a List of Fixtures (think football (or soccer for the yanks) fixtures). Each fixture contains a home and away team and a home and away score.  I want to get all the teams that drew.  I want to use something like

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew = from fixture in fixtures
                         where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
                         select fixture.HomeTeam && fixture.AwayTeam;
```

I know this syntax is incorrect, what I don't know is if it's possible to do this. Would I need two queries and then concatenate them?

**Edit: this is really a learning thing so it's not critical to achieve this in any particular way. Basically, at this stage all i want is a list of teams that have drawn.  An example usage might be that for a given list of fixtures i can find all of the drawn teams so that i could update their standings in a table by 1 point (3 for a win, 0 for a loss).**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you're looking for the Union method as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew = (from fixture in fixtures
                     where fixture.Played 
                        && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
                     select fixture.HomeTeam)
                     .Union(from fixture in fixtures
                     where fixture.Played 
                        && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
                     select fixture.AwayTeam);
```

Comment: Is there any LINQ keyword equivalent of the `.Union()` method?

Comment: @NikhilGirraj No, I don't think there is.  'Union' is not one of the LINQ keywords: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/query-keywords

And, I expect that if it exisited then it would have been used in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/return-the-set-union-of-two-sequences

Comment: For this  Linq,  The SQL Generated is INNER Join ?

Answer (score 34):

[101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx), namely Select - Anonymous Types 1

```
... select new { HomeTeam = fixture.HomeTeam, AwayTeam = fixture.AwayTeam };
```

Comment: Not the answer he's looking for.  He wants a list of Teams, not a list of anonymous types with hometeam and awayteam properties.

Comment: This is true... i could get round it using anonymous types... just wondered if there was a way to get just a list of teams.  If it's the only way it's the only way though

Comment: I agree that this doesn't return a list of teams, but i thinks its better for him to adapt his code to suport handling this anon type.  If James Hay could update his question to describe his usuage that might help.

Comment: I think his question already describes his requirement perfectly: "I want to get a list of teams that drew."  There are lots of reasons he might not want to use anonymous types here (needing to pass the list outside this method would be a common one).

Comment: Since the original post, tuples have been added to .Net/C# and might be an option in many places where an anonymous type can be used.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/

Comment: For this  Linq,  The SQL Generated is INNER Join.

Answer (score 34):

The following will return an IEnumerable<Team>:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    from fixture in fixtures
    where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
    from team in new[]{fixture.HomeTeam, fixture.AwayTeam}
    select team;
```

Or, with the fluent style of LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    fixtures
    .Where(fxtr => fxtr.Played && (fxtr.HomeScore == fxtr.AwayScore))
    .SelectMany(fixture => new[]{fixture.HomeTeam, fixture.AwayTeam});
```

### Flattening and FlatMap

This requirement is often called 'flattening'.  That is, taking a <Collection of <Collections of Things>> and converting it to a <Collection of Things>.

`SelectMany` both maps (a fixture to an Array of Teams) and flattens (a sequence of Team Arrays to a sequence of Teams).  It is similar to the "flatMap" function in other languages such as Java and JavaScript.

It is possible to separate the Mapping and the Flattening:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    fixtures
    .Where(fxtr => fxtr.Played && (fxtr.HomeScore == fxtr.AwayScore))
    // map 
    .Select(fixture => new[]{fixture.HomeTeam, fixture.AwayTeam})
    // flatten
    .SelectMany(teams => teams);
```

### Other Approaches

#### Iterator Block

The same can be achieved with an iterator block, but I suspect this is rarely the best approach:

```
IEnumerable<Team> Drew(IEnumerable<Fixture> fixtures){
    var draws = 
      fixtures
      .Where(fxtr => fxtr.Played && (fxtr.HomeScore == fxtr.AwayScore));

    foreach(var fixture in draws){
        yield return fixture.HomeTeam;
        yield return fixture.AwayTeam;
    }
}
```

#### Union

Union is also an option but has the potential to produce different results from the above:

1. The order of results will be different.  All Home results are returned then all Away results.
2. `Union` enumerates fixtures twice, so, depending on how fixtures is implemented, there is the potential for fixtures to be updated between calls.  E.g., if a new drawn fixture were added between calls then the Away team could be returned but not the Home team.

As Mike Powell describes:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    ( from fixture in fixtures
      where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
      select fixture.HomeTeam
    ).Union(
      from fixture in fixtures
      where fixture.Played  && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
      select fixture.AwayTeam );
```

Depending on how fixtures is sourced/implemented it may be worth considering 'caching' the drawn fixtures to avoid having to enumerate fixtures twice.

```
var draws = 
    ( from fixture in fixtures
      where fixture.Played  && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
      select fixture
    ).ToList();

IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    (from draw in draws select draw.HomeTeam)
    .Union(from draw in draws select draw.AwayTeam);
```

Or using the fluent style:

```
var draws = 
    fixtures
    .Where(fxtr => fxtr.Played && (fxtr.HomeScore == fxtr.AwayScore))
    .ToList();

IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    draws.Select(fixture => fixture.HomeTeam)
    .Union(draws.Select(fixture => fixture.AwayTeam));
```

#### Modifying the Fixture class

One could consider adding "ParticipatingTeams" to the Fixture class to get:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    from fixture in fixtures
    where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
    from team in fixture.ParticipatingTeams
    select team;
```

but as @MattDeKrey points out that requires a contract change.

### Code Samples

Code samples are available on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@codybartfast/SO-Selecting-Multiple-Objects-in-a-Linq-Query)

Comment: +1 for your first query - doesn't require a contract change and is more efficient than the leading answer.

Answer (score 14):

Taking a stab at this myself I came up with the same version as 'it depends'.

Using query comprehension syntax:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    from fixture in fixtures
    where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
    from team in new[]{fixture.AwayTeam, fixture.HomeTeam}
    select team;
```

Using lambda with extension methods:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    fixtures.Where(f => f.Played && f.HomeScore == f.AwayScore)
    .SelectMany(f => new[]{f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam});
```

**Edit:** I don't know if a team could have possibly played and drawn more than once in your database, but if that's possible, then you might want to make use of the `Distinct` query  operator:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    (from fixture in fixtures
     where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
     from team in new[]{fixture.AwayTeam, fixture.HomeTeam}
     select team).Distinct();
```

or:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
    fixtures.Where(f => f.Played && f.HomeScore == f.AwayScore)
    .SelectMany(f => new[]{f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam})
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Last sample worked for me. Also taught me that you can use type inference to declare arrays. Every day is a school day.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can define a type to hold all that data:

```
IEnumerable<TeamCluster> drew = from fixture in fixtures
                         where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
                         select new TeamCluster {
                             Team1 = fixture.HomeTeam,
                             Team2 = fixture.AwayTeam,
                             Score1 = fixture.HomeScore,
                             Score2 = fixture.AwayScore
                         };

class TeamCluster {
    public Team Team1 { get; set; }
    public Team Team2 { get; set; }
    public int Score1 { get; set; }
    public int Score2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Sorry, misunderstood your original question, so rewrote answer.

You could use the "SelectMany" operator to do what you want:

```
IEnumerable<Team> drew =
           (from fixture in fixtures
            where fixture.Played && (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore)
                  select new List<Team>()
                             { HomeTeam = fixture.HomeTeam,
                               AwayTeam = fixture.AwayTeam
                             }).SelectMany(team => team);
```

This will return a flattened list of teams that drew.

Answer (score 1):

I came up against this very issue, and couldn't find what I wanted so I wrote a small extension method which did what I wanted.

```
public static IEnumerable<R> MapCombine<M, R>(this IEnumerable<M> origList, params Func<M, R>[] maps)
{
    foreach (var item in origList)
    foreach (var map in maps)
    {
        yield return map(item);
    }
}
```

Following the problem in the question, you would then do something like this

```
var drew = fixtures.Where(fixture => fixture.Played && 
                        (fixture.HomeScore == fixture.AwayScore))
                    .MapCombine(f => f.HomeTeam, f => f.AwayTeam);
```

Interestingly intellisense isn't exactly happy about this, you don't get the lamdba expression in the top of the drop down, however after the '=>' its quite happy. But the main thing is the compiler is happy.