# WCF test client, join query's

Tags: c#, wcf

I am currently trying to use two tables from a database using join queries for a wcf client however it does not allow me to select both tables in the query, this is what I have tried

```
Customer customer = (from p in TaxEnities.Customers
                     where p.Customer_Id == id
                     join t in TaxEnities.Bands on p.Band equals t.Band1 
                     select p && t).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean it does not allow you?

Comment: Error appearing at "Select p && t, error is operator '&&' cannot be applied to operators of type 'Customer' and 'Band'

Comment: Then it means your syntax is wrong, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520788/can-i-select-multiple-objects-in-a-linq-query